# Simplest algorithm for zooming an image in Python by K factor

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing, zooming

I'm a total newbie to Python.

What's the simplest algorithm by which I can zoom an image by a factor of 3?
I don't want to use the already made zoom functions available.

Comment: Have you tried implementing the algorithm? It is basic data manipulation, using arrays

Comment: No, I haven't. The algorithm is what I'm looking for. If I get an algorithm for the K factor zooming, I can tweak it a little bit but I can't write one on my own.

Comment: The link attached by you (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dip/zooming_methods.htm) has mentioned the steps. What's the issue then?

Comment: The issue is that I'm confused about how to convert those steps into code lines. If you can write code lines for it, please do so, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task is moderately cumbersome, so I have shown a simple way to implement row zooming. You can similarly modify the indexes to implement column indexing for `new_image` as well.

```py
# loading the image
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
image = np.asarray( Image.open("img.jpg") )
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create new image of correct size
m = len(image[0])
n = len(image)
factor = 3
new_image = np.zeros((factor*(n-1) + 1,factor*(m-1) + 1,3), dtype=int)

# implement row zooming
for i in range(n):
    row = image[i]
    for k in range(len(row)-1):
        new_image[i][k*factor], new_image[i][(k+1)*factor] = row[k], row[k+1]
        for mode in range(3):
            # need mode as three colour channels in RGB

            lo = int(min(row[k][mode], row[k+1][mode]))
            hi = int(max(row[k][mode], row[k+1][mode]))
            diff = int((hi-lo)//factor)
            for x in range(factor-1):
                new_image[i][k*factor+1+x][mode] = lo + (x*diff)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us say you have a .png image named lenna.png on you file system. You can load it and convert it to a numpy array like this

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
image = np.asarray( Image.open("lenna.png") )
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

[image: original image]
Numpy offers a simple wayto increase the pixel resolution like this:

```
# Simply increase the resolution of the image by repeating the pixels
zoom_factor = 3
for i in range(2):
    image = np.repeat(image, zoom_factor, axis=i)
```

If we plot the image it now simply has more pixels in each dimension:
[image: Higher resolution image]

You could then display only part of the image by cropping your new high resolution image like this

```
# Focus on any paricular region by croping it out
image = image[700:1000, 700:1000]
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

The result looks like this
[image: Zoom in on lennas eye]

Cheers!

Comment: Okay, I understand this, but this is the pixel replication method. Isn't there's an algorithm for K-times zooming? In which both pixel values are subtracted and then divided by the factor K, then the result is added to the smaller pixel value.
I want to zoom by a factor of 3.

Comment: How do you mean? Would you like to distort the image, such that the pixels no longer have the exact same values as in the original image? Then I guess you are not actually zooming. I guess you are trying to say you would like to run a mean filter of size 3x3? That is to say, you would like to downsample the image?

Comment: No, the resultant value is added between the two original pixels.

I'm trying to follow the K-times zooming method in this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dip/zooming_methods.htm